# CSS rotated transition behaving differently in windows and linux

Tags: linux, windows, css, css-transitions, icon-fonts

#### The problem

This is quite a bizarre issue. I designed a website on linux and threw in some CSS transitions with rotations. At the end it would look like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0T1jXSNW6SU), (I tapped it so you can see it). 
You can see the cycling thingy spinon its own axis. This was captured on firefox but it behave exactly the same in Chrome and Opera. (most recent version of them all)

Now when I go on windows, [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIg23jwqUrw) is what I see in Firefox & chrome (both are most recent versions). It doesn't spin on its axis anymore.

#### What's inside?

Nothing in particular. Just the necessary for transitional rotations, with a few mixins to make it cross-browser. I made this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/swHbI) to show you, but I really can't find where the problem can be.

Maybe someone how has more knowledge about how windows/linux can explain this difference.
As you can see it, I'm using a icon font. Windows and linux both perform a few optimizations on type, which are known to be different. Is this by any chance related?